# Election threads after election completion

Tags: discussion, election, feedback

Will [the current EL&U moderator elections](https://english.stackexchange.com/election) thread be available for reading after election?

How, for example, to access election threads on past SO moderators elections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like so

https://stackoverflow.com/election

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election

etc